# How to make a single button appear on only 1 jquery function

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have a button called add to profile, all I need to know is how do I make it so its only on the last jQuery div, after the last next.

Like question 1, then next, question 2 back and next, question 3, back and add button.
So if you can really help me out here quick I'd really appreciate it.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var oldOption;
var counter = 1;
var maxThings = 4;
var minThings = 1;
$("#2").hide();
$("#3").hide();
$("#4").hide();
$('#back').hide();

$("#forward").click(function () {
    $("#1").hide();
    $("#2").hide();
    $("#3").hide();
    $("#4").hide();
    if (!(counter >= maxThings)) {
        counter++;
    }
    $("#" + counter).show();
    $('#back').show();
    if (counter === maxThings) {
        $('#forward').hide();
    }
});

$("#back").click(function () {
    $("#1").hide();
    $("#2").hide();
    $("#3").hide();
    $("#4").hide();
    if (!(counter <= 1)) {
        counter--;
    }

    $("#" + counter).show();
    $('#forward').show();
    if (counter === minThings) {
        $('#back').hide();
    }

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want a selector like `div:last-child`?  Your question isn't 100% clear

Comment: umm, im not completely sure, basicly I just want this button to pop up on the last div which are #1, #2, #3, and #4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
    if (counter === maxThings) {
        $('#forward').hide();
        $("#AddToProfile").show();
    } else {
        $("#AddToProfile").hide();
    }
...
```

And I really don't like youre coding :) You'll have to change code every time you'll add new div.
I would do something like that:
- Every div would have class question 
- Every div's START visibility attribute would be defined in html (every div except first would have in style something like visibility:hidden)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var oldOption;
var counter = 1;
var maxThings = 4;
var minThings = 1;
$('#back').hide();

$("#forward").click(function () {
$("div.question").hide();

    if (!(counter >= maxThings)) {
        counter++;
    }
    $("#" + counter).show();
    $('#back').show();
    if (counter === maxThings) {
        $('#forward').hide();
    }
});

$("#back").click(function () {
    $("div.question").hide();
    if (!(counter <= 1)) {
        counter--;
    }

    $("#" + counter).show();
    $('#forward').show();
    if (counter === minThings) {
        $('#back').hide();
    }

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you have button on html page?